# ArrayAdapter suggest based on string occurrence anywhere in word rather than at beginning

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I would like to have a word and its translation in another language represented in an arrayadapter in an activity of my app. I can't have it listed separately by both translation and the word itself. The ideal situation would be to have each listing in the adapter show up in a form like this

> word1 (trans1)
>
> word2 (trans2)
>
> etc. (etc.)

and have whatever the user inputs into the search bar with the array adapter, the array adapter suggests the correct word to them by either translation or title. Basically, if the input exists in the string, it should be suggested.

I'm unaware of how to write a custom way of sorting out the values in the arrayadapter and how to decide what is listed, but I need it to look for the input anywhere in the string, not just at the very beginning like it does currently.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Still not having any ideas. Looked at the documentation and couldn't find any useful methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to obtain res-string for chosen locale :

```
Locale locale = new Locale("fr");
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
getResources().getString(R.string.your_string);
```

In advance you should safe an instance of local right before changing it, so that you can reset it to original state.

If you're using `String` in your class - then you should change it to `int` so you can refer to the resource identifier.

For your list of items you can store some version of strings (by locale) to filter afterwards easily.

Now filtering.

You have to add filter to your Adapter via

```
adapter.setFilter(filterString)
```

Add SearchView to your layout and write something like this

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            AndroidUtils.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(final String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

    });
```

Adapter should contain 2 lists of data : filtered and source. Push context to the constructor of adapter to retrieve strings from resources.

Your adapter should implement `Filterable`. Then override method `getFilter()` . It will be something like this :

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter(){
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            constraint = constraint.length()>0? constraint.toString().toLowerCase():"";
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint.toString().length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Integer> filterList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(Integer current: sourceListInAdapter){
                   if(getString(textForFilter).toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                        filterList.add(current);
                    }
                }
                result.values = filterList;
                result.count = filterList.size();
            }else {
                result.values = sourceListInAdapter;
                result.count = sourceListInAdapter.size();
            }
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            temporaryData = (ArrayList<Integer>) results.values;
            //TEMPORARY data is data which is used in appearance.
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

}

In function `Filter#performFiltering` produce your own logic of search. I show just way to filter it. In this case results will be filtered out by current (device) locale with current locale results.

And one more thing. About locale detection. This can be helpful for you :

```
public String localeToString(Locale l) {
    return l.getLanguage() + "," + l.getCountry();
}

public Locale stringToLocale(String s) {
    StringTokenizer tempStringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(s,",");
    if(tempStringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    String l = tempStringTokenizer.nextElement();
    if(tempStringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    String c = tempStringTokenizer.nextElement();
    return new Locale(l,c);
}
```

Hope, it helps